# ngIf on div containing dynamically generated compoent

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a dynamically generated component which generates on run time. following is the .ts file

```
`@ViewChild(TermsheetDirective) termHost: TermsheetDirective;
    @Input() term;
    @Input() title = '';
    @Input() Qnumber = '';
    @Output() result = new EventEmitter<any>();
    section_title = '';
    number = '';
    component = [];
    show = false;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.number = this.Qnumber;
        this.section_title = this.title;
    }


    ngAfterViewInit() {
    }
    ngAfterContentInit() {

    }
    loadcomponents() {
        console.log(this.termHost);
        for (let j = 0; j < this.term.components.length; j++) {
            let termItem = this.term.components[j];
            let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(termItem.component);
            let viewContainerRef = this.termHost.viewContainerRef;
            let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
            (<TermComponent>componentRef.instance).data = termItem.data;
            this.component[j] = componentRef;
        }
    }
    getdata() {
        let output = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.component.length; i++) {
            let temp = {
                slug : this.section_title,
                type : this.component[i].type,
                value : this.component[i]._component.getdata()
            };
             output[i] = temp;
        }
        this.result.emit(output);
        return output;
    }
    showcomp() {
        console.log("In if");
        this.show = true;
        this.loadcomponents();

    }
    hidecomp() {
        this.show = false;
    }`
```

and following is my html

```
`<div class="main">
  <div class="div_for_ques">
    <div class="question">
      <div class="number">
        {{number}}
      </div>
      <div class="textbox">
        {{section_title}}
      </div>
        <div class="arrow" *ngIf="!show">
            <a (click)="showcomp()" class="glyphicon">&#xe080;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow" *ngIf="show">
            <a (click)="hidecomp()" class="glyphicon">&#xe080;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sec_two" *ngIf="show">
      <ng-template term-host></ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

I want the div that contains the dynamically generated component to appear only when a certain button is clicked. but i am having following response.[image]

But when I try to show this div without ngIf it is working fine. But with ngIf termHost is undefined! Can someone please explain what is happening here!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are trying to reference to **viewContainerRef** before change detection cycle has completed, that is why you get that error.

There is more than one solution to this, you can use a setter for the **ViewChild**, that will be called once after the *ngIf becomes true

e.g

```
@ViewChild('') set content(x:x) {
this.x = x;
```

}

**OR** you can inject the change detector manually

```
constructor(private changeDetector : ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

You can then call it after you click your button

```
this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
```

**OR** You can also use a **QueryList** to achieve the same effect because you can subscribe to changes

Please apply these techniques to your logic to solve your problem

Comment: I have tries changeDetector but no luck! I called load component after this.changeDetector.detectChanges() but getting same error!

Comment: can you provide a tiny example of how i can use querylist?